# Array's onChanged property doesn't get called when pushing items in it on mouseclicks in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

### ***Access.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: newq

    width: 100
    height: 62

    property var pp : [1]

    onPpChanged:
    {
        console.log("\non pp changed, show pp's length: " +  pp.length)
    }

    property int inde : 0

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            pp.push (inde++)
            console.log("mousearea shows pp's length: " + pp.length)
        }
    }
}
```

### ***main.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Access
    {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

### ***Output (on mouse clicks):***

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

on pp changed, show pp's length: 1
mousearea shows pp's length: 2
mousearea shows pp's length: 3
mousearea shows pp's length: 4
mousearea shows pp's length: 5
```

***Why isn't the onPpChanged getting called when I push the items in pp? What can I do to get it called?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because arrays in QML are not QML Objects. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-variant.html#storing-arrays-and-objects) says:

> Additionally, since [...] are not QML objects, changing their individual values do not trigger property change notifications. If the above example had onNumberChanged or onAnimalChanged signal handlers, they would not have been called. If, however, the items or attributes properties themselves were reassigned to different values, then such handlers would be called.

So for your code to work you need to throw the signal yourself when modifying the array. So your code should look like this:

```
  MouseArea
  {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked:
      {
          pp.push(inde++);
          ppChanged();
          console.log("mousearea shows pp's length: " + pp.length);
      }
  }
```